# DispatchQueue threads don't always set the correct results

Tags: ios, swift, grand-central-dispatch, semaphore, dispatch-async

Am trying on coding game MineSweeper, the following code is to set the numbers around landmines. For a test, I choose the minimum level 9 x 9 with 10 landmines.

For a faster performance, I tried to use more threads when setting numbers, but one day I found that it doesn't always give the correct number arrangements, I made a loop to create it 1000 times and found that 20 ~ 40 out of 1000 are wrong.

Here are several wrong results, "*" represents landmine, "0" means no landmine around

wrong mine:  index 1 should be "*"

```
10212*100
112*21211
0011101*1
000000111
000011100
01123*200
01*2**200
023432100
01**10000
```

wrong num:  index 0 should be "1"

```
0*212*100
112*21211
0011101*1
000000111
000011100
01123*200
01*2**200
023432100
01**10000
```

wrong num:  index 73 should be "1"

```
1*212*100
112*21211
0011101*1
000000111
000011100
01123*200
01*2**200
023432100
00**10000
```

Without using DispatchQueue or set DispatchSemaphore's value to 1, it gives the correct number arrangement in 1000%1000.

```
1*212*100
112*21211
0011101*1
000000111
000011100
01123*200
01*2**200
023432100
01**10000
```

Here is the sample code:

```
// actually indexes created randomly every time
let minesIndexArr = [59, 74, 1, 12, 50, 56, 75, 58, 5, 25]
var defaultCellArr = [String]()
var totalCellArr = [String]()
var count = 0

for _ 1...81 {
    defaultCellArr.append("0")
}

runLoop()

func runLoop() {
    if count == 1000 {
        return
    }
    totalCellArr = defaultCellArr
    setNums()
}

func setNums() {
    let group = DispatchGroup()
    let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "com.setnums", attributes: .concurrent)
    let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 10)
    for i in 0..<self.totalCellArr.count {
        semaphore.wait()
        group.enter()
        queue.async(group: group, execute: {
            if self.minesIndexArr.firstIndex(of: i) != nil{
                self.totalCellArr[i] = "*"
            }else{
                var num = 0
                let neighbourIndexes = self.getNeighbourIndex(i)
                for v in neighbourIndexes.values {
                    if self.minesIndexArr.firstIndex(of: v) != nil {
                        num += 1
                    }
                }
                self.totalCellArr[i] = String(num)
            }
                            
            group.leave()
            semaphore.signal()
        })
        
    }
    group.notify(queue: DispatchQueue.main) {
        printMap()
        count += 1
        self.runLoop()
    }
}
```

Comment: By the way, I might suggest turning on TSAN (the [Thread Sanitizer](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/diagnosing_memory_thread_and_crash_issues_early)) and it would undoubtedly have warned you about all of these data races.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tl;dr

You are using this non-zero semaphore to do parallel calculations, constraining the degree of concurrency to something reasonable. I would recommend `concurrentPerform`.

But the issue here is not how you are constraining the degree of the parallelism, but rather that you are using the same properties (shared by all of these concurrent tasks) for your calculations, which means that one iteration on one thread can be mutating these properties while they are being used/mutated by another parallel iteration on another thread.

So, I would avoid using any shared properties at all (short of the final array of boards). Use local variables only. And make sure to synchronize the updating of this final array so that you don't have two threads mutating it at the same time.

---

So, for example, if you wanted to create the boards in parallel, I would probably use `concurrentPerform` as outlined in [my prior answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64739691/1271826):

```
func populateBoards(count: Int, rows: Int, columns: Int, mineCount: Int, completion: @escaping ([Board]) -> Void) {
    var boards: [Board] = []
    let lock = NSLock()

    DispatchQueue.global().async {
        DispatchQueue.concurrentPerform(iterations: count) { index in
            let board = Board(rows: rows, columns: columns, mineCount: mineCount)
            lock.synchronize {
                boards.append(board)
            }
        }
    }

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        lock.synchronize {
            completion(boards)
        }
    }
}
```

Note, I'm not referencing any ivars. It is all local variables, passing the result back in a closure.

And to avoid race conditions where multiple threads might be trying to update the same array of boards, I am synchronizing my access with a `NSLock`. (You can use whatever synchronization mechanism you want, but locks a very performant solution, probably better than a GCD serial queue or reader-writer pattern in this particular scenario.) That `synchronize` method is as follows:

```
extension NSLocking {
    func synchronize<T>(block: () throws -> T) rethrows -> T {
        lock()
        defer { unlock() }
        return try block()
    }
}
```

That is a nice generalized solution (handling closures that might return values, throw errors, etc.), but if that is too complicated to follow, here is a minimalistic rendition that is sufficient for our purposes here:

```
extension NSLocking {
    func synchronize(block: () -> Void) {
        lock()
        block()
        unlock()
    }
}
```

Now, I confess, that I'd probably employ a different model for the board. I would define a `Square` enum for the individual squares of the board, and then define a `Board` which was an array (for rows) of arrays (for columns) for all these squares. Anyway, this in my implementation of the `Board`:

```
enum Square {
    case count(Int)
    case mine
}

struct Board {
    let rows: Int
    let columns: Int
    var squares: [[Square]]

    init(rows: Int, columns: Int, mineCount: Int) {
        self.rows = rows
        self.columns = columns

        // populate board with all zeros

        self.squares = (0..<rows).map { _ in
            Array(repeating: Square.count(0), count: columns)
        }

        // now add mines

        addMinesAndUpdateNearbyCounts(mineCount)
    }

    mutating func addMinesAndUpdateNearbyCounts(_ mineCount: Int) {
        let mines = (0..<rows * columns)
            .map { index in
                index.quotientAndRemainder(dividingBy: columns)
            }
            .shuffled()
            .prefix(mineCount)

        for (mineRow, mineColumn) in mines {
            squares[mineRow][mineColumn] = .mine
            for row in mineRow-1 ... mineRow+1 where row >= 0 && row < rows {
                for column in mineColumn-1 ... mineColumn+1 where column >= 0 && column < columns  {
                    if case .count(let n) = squares[row][column] {
                        squares[row][column] = .count(n + 1)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

extension Board: CustomStringConvertible {
    var description: String {
        var result = ""

        for row in 0..<rows {
            for column in 0..<columns {
                switch squares[row][column] {
                    case .count(let n): result += String(n)
                    case .mine: result += "*"
                }
            }
            result += "\n"
        }

        return result
    }
}
```

Anyway, I would generate 1000 9×9 boards with ten mines each like so:

```
exercise.populateBoards(count: 1000, rows: 9, columns: 9, mineCount: 10) { boards in
    for board in boards {
        print(board)
        print("")
    }
}
```

But feel free to use whatever model you want. But I'd suggest encapsulating the model for the Board in its own type. It not only abstracts the details of the generation of a board from the multithreaded algorithm to create lots of boards, but it naturally avoids any unintended sharing of properties by the various threads.

---

Now all of this said, this is not a great example of parallelized code because the creation of a board is not nearly computationally intensive enough to justify the (admittedly very minor) overhead of running it in parallel. This is not a problem that is likely to benefit much from parallelized routines. Maybe you'd see some modest performance improvement, but not nearly as much as you might experience from something a little more computationally intensive.

Comment: Know from the beginning of you answer and online searching, Dictionary and Array are unsafe in threads, that might be the reason it gives incorrect result occasionally. Your model give me a new idea how to setup the board, currently I use UICollectionView as the game board which may be not a better way, I may try to code in your way later, and again the instruction of GCD do help! Thanks a lot.